# What is the delegate method that is called when an MKPinAnnotationView is touched?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I have been searching for this all night and I have just so frustrated. When a MKPinAnnotationView is clicked, the name and the subtitle comes up. I also want to center that point on the view. I figured there was some method I had to override because the information that pops up happened without me having to code it. Hopefully this was clear enough for you all.

And in the mean time, I feel like there is some hidden guide on this use of MKMaps and other classes. Either that or it is terribly documented because I am having a lot of trouble finding information. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried overriding setSelected:animated:? (defined in [MKAnnotationView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKAnnotationView/setSelected:animated:))

Comment: No because I was using the MKPinAnnotationView that was given, I didn't subclass it.

Comment: And the MKAnnotationView doesn't know about my MKMapView because that is the class that calls it.

Comment: I know this is messy, but I would subclass MKPinAnnotationView that does two things:

1) Holds a reference to a MKMapView that you set when creating the annotation
2) Overrides setSelected:animated: to center the map

Comment: Hello, I am also needing help with this, specifically centering the annotation callout on the map. Does anyone have working code for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{
}
```

This is the method that is called when you tap on a pin.

Comment: This method is called after the MKPinAnnotation has shown on screen.